# How to pass data from page to user control and vise versa in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a main page called Mainpage1 and inside that page one usercontrol called UC1 and inside that usercontrol we have another usercontrol called UC2.

Here I want to pass the data from UC2 to Mainpage and vise versa. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance
Siva

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use javascript or AJAX.  So make a javascript function that hooks into UC2's change event.  Inside that function you can change the css/html/etc on the main page.  If what you're trying to do requires you to go back to the controller for some sort of processing (i.e. checking the value against a database) then you'll need to use ajax to call the url for that action.

Without seeing any code that's the best I can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

(From [question 542410](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542410/asp-net-pass-value-from-user-control-to-page))

In the code-behind on your user-control expose a property e.g.

```
public TextBox UserControlTextBox
{
    return this.TextBoxInstance;
}
```

Then from you page just call

```
UserControlInstance.UserControlTextBox.Text;
```

Comment: The real problem is i am unable to access UC2 from mainpage1.